# How to find the correct Image size

Tags: python

I am trying to convert Text to image in Python

This is the code:
As long as the text is in single line,

For example "Text to write on img 1234567890"

It is fine
[image]

But if the text contains "\n" then the image clips and size calculations become incorrect

"Text to write on \n img 1234567890"

[image]

Please help

```
import numpy as np
import time
import text_to_image
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text="Text to write on \n img 1234567890", size=200, color=(0,0,0), bg='white'):
    "Draw a text on an Image, saves it, show it"
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size)
    # create image
    image = Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (int(size/2)*len(text),size+50), color = bg)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    # draw text
    draw.text((10,10), text, font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0))
    # save file
    image.save(filename)
    # show file
    os.system(filename)


text_on_img()
```

Comment: count how many `\n` that text have, and sum the result of the numbers of `\n`  `*` your font height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it perfectly. Please test it.

```
import os

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


def text_on_img(filename='01.png', text="Text to write on \n img 1234567890", size=200, color=(0, 0, 0), bg='white'):
    "Draw a text on an Image, saves it, show it"
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size)
    # create image

    width = max([int(size/2) * len(line) for line in text.split('\n')])
    height = (size + 50) * len(text.split('\n'))

    image = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(width, height), color=bg)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    # draw text
    draw.text((10, 10), text, font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))
    # save file
    image.save(filename)
    # show file
    os.system(filename)


text_on_img()
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: You can test with any text.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is multiplying `size` with the number of occurrences of `\n`.

```py
n = text.count('\n') + 2
# create image
image = Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (int(size/2)*len(text),size*n), color = bg)
```

Result:

---

[image]

If you remove `\n` from the text, the result will be:

[image]

Other examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]